# Pass commands using sed

Tags: shell, sh

I am using some commands as runcmd as user data:

```
[ sh, -c, 'echo "sendmail: ALL" >> /etc/hosts.allow' ]
[ sh, -c, 'systemctl restart sendmail' ]
[ sh, -c, 'echo "Subject: Instance Deployed" | sendmail /user@example.com/' ]
```

I would like to add sendmail: ALL to etc/hosts.allow and send the email with the subject line.

However, when I try the steps manually, I receive the email and am able to edit the file.

Please suggest/advice where I am going wrong.

Tried

```
[ sh, -c, 'echo "sendmail: ALL" >> /etc/hosts.allow' ]
```

but sendmail: ALL was not added to etc/hosts.allow

Comment: Is it Python ???

Comment: Thank you Gilles for the response,

shell script

Comment: What are you trying to do with brackets ? `[      ]` ???

Comment: And why commands are separated with `,` like in Python ?

Comment: Remove `[ sh, -c, '` and `' ]` from each line. Are you _sure_ you are writing a unix "shell script"?

Comment: What is "runcmd"? What you are showing isn't shell syntax; you are apparently embedding shell commands in some other context.

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
echo "sendmail: ALL" >> /etc/hosts.allow
```

As said by [KamilCuk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75174198/pass-commands-using-sed/75174291#comment132655180_75174198), Remove `[ sh, -c, '` and `' ]` from each line.